# Formatting Array made from html classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on implementing a review system into my website and am stuck at this point:

I take all the product SKUs which are only accessible from the Cart page like such:

```
<span class="ProdSkus">SKU1</span>
<span class="ProdSkus">SKU2</span>
<span class="ProdSkus">SKU3</span>
```

I'm combining these into an array with this:

```
var combinedText = $('.ProdSkus').text();
```

When I log it I get this result:

```
SKU1SKU2SKU3
```

I need to format it to be as such:

```
["SKU1", "SKU2", ...]
```

Any help is appreciated!

This has to be done from the cart page, stored locally, and then used after the customer has made the purchase. I have been doing this like such:

```
localStorage.setItem("SKUS", combinedText);
```

Comment: You can't store an array in `localStorage`, you need to convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the set of elements and add each value to an array:

```js
var combinedText = [];  // This is where the results will go

// Loop over the matched elements
$('.ProdSkus').each(function(){
  // Add the text of each span to the array
  combinedText.push(this.textContent);
});

// Test the result
console.log(combinedText);

// And, to store the values in localStorage,
// you'd need to convert the array into a string
// This will throw an error here in Stack Overflow because
// their snippet environment doesn't allow it, but the code is correct:
localStorage.setItem("combinedText", JSON.stringify(combinedText));

// Then, when/where you want the data back out of localStorage, you'd write
var gottenData = localStorage.getItem("combinedText");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ProdSkus">SKU1</span>
<span class="ProdSkus">SKU2</span>
<span class="ProdSkus">SKU3</span>
```

Comment: This works great! It's formatted exactly as needed. Thank you!

Comment: @Matt You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote all the helpful answers and mark one (maybe this one?) as your answer.

Comment: Apparently I cannot do that as of yet, ha. Need 15 rep, but I have upvoted these! Now my next task is to convert it to be stored in local storage, I think stringify does this?

Comment: @Matt All you'd need to do is `localStorage.setItem("combinedText", JSON.stringify(combinedText));`

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map()`:

```
var combinedText = $('.ProdSkus').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

`.map()` returns a jQuery collection of the return values (strings in this case), and `.get()` converts it to an array.

Comment: Clarification: The JQuery version of `map()` returns a JQuery object containing whatever you tell it to contain. In this case, the text of the elments (strings).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `each`:

```
var combinedText = [];
$('.ProdSkus').each(function(k,v) {
    combinedText.push(v.text());
});
console.log(combinedText);
```

Comment: `v` is the element, not its text.

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JS** solution (no jQuery).

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('ProdSkus');
var arr = [];
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => arr.push(v.innerHTML));

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<span class="ProdSkus">SKU1</span>
<span class="ProdSkus">SKU2</span>
<span class="ProdSkus">SKU3</span>
```